# How to melt a dataframe so repeated items become the values that correspond to the index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, repeat, melt

I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Status':['CO','AD','AD','AD','OT','CO','OT','AD'],
                   'Mutation':['H157Y','R47H','R47H','R67H','R62H','D87N','D39E','D39E']})
print(df)
  
  Status Mutation
0     CO    H157Y
1     AD     R47H
2     AD     R47H
3     AD     R67H
4     OT     R62H
5     CO     D87N
6     OT     D39E
7     AD     D39E
```

I want the dataframe to look like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Status':['CO','AD','OT'],'H157Y':[1,0,0],'R47H':[0,2,0],'R67H':[0,1,0],
                    'R62H':[0,0,1],'D87N':[1,0,0],'D39E':[1,0,1]})
print(df2)

  Status  H157Y  R47H  R67H  R62H  D87N  D39E
0     CO      1     0     0     0     1     1
1     AD      0     2     1     0     0     0
2     OT      0     0     0     1     0     1
```

Where mutations are the column names and their values - the number of hits - corresponds to the status.

Comment: Looks like a cross tabulation to me. `pd.crosstab` docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html

See also the SO post on pivoting part 9: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe

Comment: This sounds like a `crosstab` question.

Comment: What about `df2 = df.pivot_table(index='Status', columns='Mutation', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
df2 = df2.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
`?

Comment: Definitely a `crosstab` + `reset_index`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```py
df.groupby(['Status', 'Mutation']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) like the below:

```
>>> pd.crosstab(df["Status"], df["Mutation"])

Mutation  D39E  D87N  H157Y  R47H  R62H  R67H
Status                                       
AD           1     0      0     2     0     1
CO           0     1      1     0     0     0
OT           1     0      0     0     1     0
```

Or we can use [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html), [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) then [`pandas.DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) columns like the below:

```
(pd.get_dummies(df, 
                columns=['Mutation']
               ).groupby(['Status']).sum().rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('_')[1]))
```

Output:

```
        D39E  D87N  H157Y  R47H  R62H  R67H
Status                                     
AD         1     0      0     2     0     1
CO         0     1      1     0     0     0
OT         1     0      0     0     1     0
```

Comment: Not sure why you reopened... The duplicate was correct

Comment: I sincerely want to understand, I did not get your point. Do you believe this was not closed correctly? Check the answer #5 in the link this is exactly what is needed.

Comment: OK, it's your right, I am very sorry that you feel this way. No harm intended from my side.